# Candy Machine, Sugar Upload error

Tags: metaplex, sugar, candy

I'm new to Candy Machine / Sugar and I'm following the 'My First Candy Machine' tutorial:
https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/tutorials/my-first-candy-machine

I've got to the 'sugar upload' part and I get this error:

```
[1/4]   Loading assets

Found 10 asset pair(s), uploading files:

+--------------------+

| images    |     10 |

| metadata  |     10 |

+--------------------+



[2/4]   Initializing upload



 Error running command (re-run needed): error sending request for url (http://localhost:8899/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)
```

I can't find ANYTHING on Google or on Solana Stack Exchange about this issue.

How can I fix it and upload the assets?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you might have missed a step, what does `solana config get` tell you? At the start, it asks you to configure a [devnet wallet](https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/cli-wallet#setting-up-a-devnet-wallet-for-testing) ... give it a shot, and btw quicknode has a free RPC plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the rpc to devnet/mainnet in your `solana config`.

For devnet you can use `solana config set -u devnet`, then make sure to have enough devnet sol using `solana airdrop 2` and then you can use `sugar upload` and the rest of the tutorial.

For mainnet you will need a mainnet rpc (you will have to buy one), and you will need rial SOL.

Comment: NFA you have a list of RPC providers here https://docs.metaplex.com/resources/rpc-providers choose whatever fits your necesities